# How to solve the OSError while Importing torch in Python

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, anaconda, pytorch

Information:

- OS: Windows 8.1 64-bit
- Python: 3.7.3 64-bit
- Anaconda: 64-bit

Agenda:

To make sure `python -c "import torch"` works without any errors.

Process:

I have created my environment using `conda create -n myenv`

After which with great difficulty I have further installed `conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit -c pytorch`

When the above command was executed, it was interrupted midway due to HTTPRequest failure

After several such failures, I have installed pytorch using `conda install pytorch -c pytorch`

When I type `python -c "import torch"` I get OSError like the one below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\sanpj\.conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    import numpy as _np  # noqa: F401
  File "C:\Users\sanpj\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\Users\sanpj\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "C:\Users\sanpj\.conda\envs\myenv\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

But the output should not be as such.

When I type in `python`, I get some information as mentioned below

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2019, 15:29:51) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: You can use anaconda prompt to install these libraries in place of command prompt if you are getting HTTPRequest failure(obviously by first activating the virtual environment myenv). By default, environment is set to base in anaconda prompt. I think that will work.

Comment: Thanks for the input @AnubhavSingh, I used anaconda & installed in my virtual environment `myenv` but the problem was during runtime while trying to import torch. I think there is some bug in the newer versions of torch, numpy modules.
After I downgraded the module versions, it worked !!

Comment: Actually the same thing happened with me yesterday while installing pytorch, although it was cpu-version via windows command prompt in virtual env. When I tried the same using anaconda prompt, I was able to install the libraries. However, my python version was 3.5.5

Comment: Oh.. I see.
What are the versions of numpy & torch ?

Comment: Numpy: 1.16.1 Torch: 1.1.0 (cpu-based)

Comment: My version of python was 3.7.3(latest) 64-bit
I had the same versions of both initially, which is when I obtained the mentioned error in runtime
I downgraded to Numpy: 1.12.1 torch: 1.0.1 or something I guess
I didn't get the mentioned exception in runtime.

Did you try and import numpy/torch in python command prompt ?
Was it successful ?!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

Actually, I downgraded to older versions of torch, torchvision & numpy as well.
That actually solved this issue.